Continue in 6x6 Towers puzzle

How can I continue with this Towers puzzle?

In addition to the provided answer, 5 cannot be the second number for a 2 clue (R2C5) or the first number for a 3 clue (R3C6)

@bobble The screenshot appears to be from Simon Tatham's Puzzle app.

With Simon Tatham puzzles, you can get an ID number to share a specific puzzle.

In row 5:

 The 2-clue on the left means that the row has to begin with a value that is larger than all those following it up until the 6 on that row. Therefore the row must begin with 3, 2, 1, 6.

